# Minima of a random walk and an equality for a fraction

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, asymptotics, random-walks

Let $S_n := X_1 + \dots + X_n$ denote a random walk with zero mean and finite variance and write $L_n := \min \{ 0, S_1, \dots, S_n\}$. The tail distribution of $L_n$ are well-known and in particular,
\begin{align}
P(L_n \geq 0) \sim c n^{-1/2}
\end{align}
for some constant $c> 0$. Now, I read the following statement in a paper:
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (if you want, you can choose $n$ large) and $\alpha > 1$, then
\begin{align}
\frac{P(L_{\lfloor \alpha n \rfloor} \geq 0)}{P(L_n \geq 0)} \geq \alpha^{-1/2}.
\end{align}
This is extremely surprising to me. Obviously, we have as $n \to \infty$ that the fraction converges to $\alpha^{-1/2}$, but the statement holds for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (or for all $n \geq N$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$) apparently.

So far, I couldn't prove it or show that it is indeed not true. Any ideas?

Edit 1: The equality was changed to an inequality.

Edit 2: I think the following is true which answers my question
\begin{align}
\frac{P(L_{\lfloor \alpha n \rfloor} \geq 0)}{P(L_n \geq 0)} = \alpha^{-1/2} + o(1),
\end{align}
and in fact, that is all that is needed, I realized.

Comment: This can non be an equality: there exist different values of $\alpha$ with the same $\lfloor \alpha n\rfloor$.

Comment: Oh, I'll make an adjustment. It actually states an inequality. Sorry. (I still think that it is not true though.)

Comment: Considering $(\alpha,n) = (i/j, j)$ and $(\alpha,n) = (j/i, i)$, one realizes that inequality for all $\alpha > 0$ actually implies equality whenever $\alpha n$ is an integer. Did you mean $\alpha > 1$? In what paper have you read this?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant $\alpha >1$. The paper is https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0503657.pdf Lemma 2.5.

Comment: Though, I am still wondering how the conditions of the DCT are guaranteed in the first part of the proof...